# Calling a method that displays the output pattern only

Tags: java, int, static-methods

I'm having a hard time with my second method, The method declaration is:
    `public static void displayOutput(int loopCount)`
The method is called from the `main()` and is passed the valid input value which determines repetition. The method displays the output pattern only and returns nothing. Every 3rd line displays a space and 3 asterisks

I know I'm not calling each method right in the `main()` and I know that `displayOutput(int loopCout)` is wrong.

Could someone explain this to me or use an example that would help write the program?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   int repeat;
   Scanner goGet = new Scanner(System.in); 
   repeat = getValidValue(goGet); //Uncompilable source code -Erroneous sym type

   displayOutput(repeat);
}

public static int getValidValue() {
    int input;

    do {
        Scanner getInfo = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter an integer Greater than zero: --> ");
        input = getInfo.nextInt();

    } while (input <= 0);

    return input;
}

public static int displayOutput(int loopCount) {
    int i; 
    for (i = 0; i < loopCount; i++) {
        System.out.print("The semester is ending soon. ");
        System.out.print("The semester is ending soon. ");
        System.out.print("The semester is ending soon.*** ");            
    }

    return loopCount;
}
```

Comment: You're asking about a compilation error. But apparently, you haven't read the error. Or at least you haven't considered useful to read it, since you haven't posted it. Read it. It tells you exactly what is wrong, and where. Something like "method getValidValue() cannot be called with an argument of type java.util.Scanner". Why? because getValidValue() doesn't take any argument, and yet you're trying to pass one when calling it.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing a value to method **getValidValue** which doesn’t take any value.

Also **displayOutput** is returning loopcount but you are not catching it anywhere so after asterisk it is not displaying anything.